# Live plot from stdin

Tags: live, plot

I have an application which prints numbers to stdout. Is there an easy way of using any commandline plot tool (gnuplot) for a live plot of the image?

Comment: It would be easy to write such a tool in Python, using `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 6):

I would highly recommend [ttyplot](https://github.com/tenox7/ttyplot), you can build live graphs directly in the terminal, reading data from STDIN

[image]

Another option is to use [sampler](https://github.com/sqshq/sampler): Tool for shell commands execution, visualization and alerting. Configured with a simple YAML file.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect the numbers to a file and read the file periodically either using gnuplot's reread command or manually pressing `e` on the plot window.

```
shell$ command > points.dat
```

In gnuplot

```
gnuplot> plot "points.dat" using 1:2
```

and press `e` on the window to update it, or see the example from

```
gnuplot> help reread
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [livechart](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/livechart) for exactly this
purpose. It's based on matplotlib and accepts either numbers or JSON objects
with numeric data via `stdin`.

```
sudo pip install livechart
```

Note that Python2.7 is recommended because matplotlib wouldn't quite work for
me under 3.x. Also, you might need to install a C++ compiler to build
matplotlib (`sudo apt-get install g++` on Debian).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [plotti.co](http://plotti.co) to export your plot to the web in a one-liner like this:

```sh
<program> | xargs -L1 sh -c 'wget -q -O /dev/null http://plotti.co/4134314?d=$0'
```

And you will view it live at address http://plotti.co/4134314/plot.svg

*Disclaimer: I am the creator of plotti.co*

Comment: Seems to be a dead link.  It would be nice if you posted an example here.